# Display math formula in the middle of a line

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am writing a report using some template with `amsmath`. The equations are displayed in a way that they are flushed to the left with certain space in front. Does anyone know how it happens? How can I change change something to make all math equations be displayed in the middle of a line?

Comment: centered display equations is the default with `amsmath`, so some template or package must be overriding this.  look for an option beginning with "fl" (flush left).  without more details regarding the packages or templates you're using, it's difficult to be more specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've probably added `fleqn` as an option to either the document class or `amsmath`. Remove it and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is this case. After removing it, it works well.:-) Actually, the first line is:
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{book}

Comment: @Anand Glad to hear it worked. Now if I may be so bold, you might consider accepting my answer.

Comment: @Torbjom, Sure I accept your answer. I am sorry that I forgot to do so. :-) Thank you very much! :-)