# equations automatically aligning to the left, how do I centre them?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I was under the impression that equations align to the centre.
I'm using a pack `\documentclass [twocolumn, final] {svjour3}` which I am guessing is changing that.

So for example this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\label{eq_vector_value}
V_{w_{xy}} &= 1 - Norm(\delta(w_{x},w_{y})) \\
           &= \{V_{w_{xy}} \in \mathbb{R} \| 0 \geq V_{w_{xy}} \geq 1\}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Produces this:

[image]

This is a two column format, and I've been trying to make it centre.
Was I wrong to expect it would automatically align to the centre?
All equations in this particular article seem to align left.

Comment: Do you have a `fleqn` option specified anywhere? See [Display math formula in the middle of a line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37579/5764).

Comment: No I don't have. It seems to default to left alignment. Can I somehow cancel it out?

Comment: what document class are you using.  maybe that specifies left alignment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton its a template from Springer, called `svjour3.cls` the type is simply defined as `\documentclass[twocolumn,final]{svjour3}`. Should I look into the document and see if theres a `fleqn`?

Comment: i've just looked into `svjour3.cls` (i have an old copy lying around), and it includes this line:  `\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}}`,  there's your answer.  that's what springer wants.

Comment: (I read the question wrongly and assumed that OP was picturing the behavior he was expecting… Thanks @barbarabeeton, I corrected my answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the class default behavior.
[svjour3.cls](http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/spr-chicago.html) includes

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}}
```

So that the default

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, final]{svjour3}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the demo
\DeclareMathOperator{\Norm}{Norm}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5] % Just for the demo
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \label{eq_vector_value}
    V_{w_{xy}} &= 1 - \Norm(\delta(w_{x},w_{y})) \\
    &= \{V_{w_{xy}} \in \mathbb{R} \| 0 \geq V_{w_{xy}} \geq 1\}.
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[5-15] % Just for the demo
\end{document}
```

produces :

[image]

(By the way, you should use a `\DeclareMathOperator` to display nicely your "Norm" in the equation.)

Comment: Many thanks for the help and hint ;-) I guess thats what Springer expects.

Answer (score 7):

[`svjour3.cls`](http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/spr-chicago.html) defines `fleqn` as a class option, but also passes that option to [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) if its loaded:

```
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{\input{fleqn.clo}\AtBeginDocument{\mathindent\z@}%
  \AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{\@mathmargin\z@}{}}%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}}
```

And, under the `twocolumn` document class option, it necessarily also uses `fleqn`, thereby adding content to the `\@begindocumenthook` and setting up `amsmath`:

```
\DeclareOption{twocolumn}{\@twocolumntrue\ExecuteOptions{fleqn}}
```

You can override this by using the following by removing any options passed to `amsmath` by the document class

```
\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname opt@amsmath.sty\endcsname\relax% Remove options passed to amsmath
\makeatother
```

The above seems sufficient, but one can also remove the margin adjustments introduced by the class:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \mathindent=15pt % Restore \mathindent
  \@mathmargin\@centering} % Restore \@mathmargin
\makeatother
```

All of the above goes against better judgement, as journals have specific requirements that one should adhere to.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, final]{svjour3}

\makeatletter
\expandafter\let\csname opt@amsmath.sty\endcsname\relax% Remove options passed to amsmath
\AtBeginDocument{
  \mathindent=15pt % Restore \mathindent
  \@mathmargin\@centering} % Restore \@mathmargin
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this document
\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice investigation. You should emphasize the sentence "All of the above goes against better judgement, as journals have specific requirements that one should adhere to." !